# Given a Java function generate a command-line wrapper [script]

Tags: java, command-line-interface, code-generation

I'm searching for something like a Java version of https://github.com/google/python-fire

I want to write a Java function that, given a reference to another Java function will give me some command-line program (e.g. a shell script) which can be launched with different arguments which are then passed to the given Java function as arguments.

How hard is this? How can I do this?

An example of `argparse`-based generated command-line wrapper for python: https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/ee527c8ad4c6fd60e8ee8a37f0653330ed0dc426/components/gcp/automl/create_dataset_for_tables/component.yaml#L80

Comment: Good for you! But what is your actual question for us?

Comment: The actual question is: How can I do the following: "Given a Java function generate a command-line wrapper [script]"?

Comment: Also: Can you please help me find or create "something like Java version of https://github.com/google/python-fire" ?

Comment: How about using reflection? You can get the method signature and from that generate a shell script with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Taking this as weekend project.

Comment: >"How about using reflection? You can get the method signature and from that generate a shell script with the appropriate arguments." - Sure. Of course it needs to start with reflecting over the function signature. It's just that I've been out of Java world for about a decade and there were thousands of libraries released in that time span. There is probably at least one that can already do that.